# check if boostrap modal is hidden using js

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

Bootstrap modals can be hidden using

`$('#myModal').modal('hide')`

or using the close icon on the corner or clicking on somewhere outside the modal.

is there a way to check if the modal was closed using the js method and whether it has been triggered using other methods?

I want to do specific actions depending on each scenairo

```
$('#myModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function (e) {
  // on js trigged close, do something
  // otherwise do something...
})
```

Comment: Looks like `hidden.bs.modal` should work fine. From docs: http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals-events

Comment: That's not really what I'm looking for.

Answer (score -1):

whenever modal is shown, it adds a `in` class into modal. so you can check if `$('#myModal')` has class in it means modal is show if not then hidden

here is exmaple:

```
    if ($('#myModal').hasClass('in')) {
      console.log('modal is shown')
    }else {
      console.log('modal is hidden')
    }
    // or

    if ($('#myModal.in').length != 0) {
      console.log('modal is shown')
    }else {
      console.log('modal is hidden')
    }
```

already tested.

Comment: That's not really what I'm asking. I want to know if a modal got hidden using the js trigger or was hidden because the user clicked on the close button or outside the modal.